# Java 8 lambda chaining predicate won't work

Tags: java, java-8, predicate

i have a list of fruits:

```
final List<Fruit> fruitList = Arrays.asList(new Fruit(1, "AA"), new Fruit(2, "DD"),
            new Fruit(3, "CC"), new Fruit(4, "BB"));
```

and a predicate of fruit

```
final Predicate<Fruit> predicate = s -> s.getName().equals("AA") && s.getId() == 10;
```

The output of the predicate

```
System.out.println(fruitList.stream().anyMatch(predicate)); -> output false
```

When i chain the predicate with another one, it won't work

```
final Predicate<Fruit> predicate = s -> s.getName().equals("AA");
predicate.and(s -> s.getId() == 10);
System.out.println(fruitList.stream().anyMatch(predicate)); -> output true
```

How it is possible?

Comment: try `predicate = predicate.and(...);` - `and()` returns a new `Predicate`.

Answer (score 2):

From the [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Predicate.html) of Predicate :

> **and(Predicate < ? super T> other)**
>
> Returns a composed predicate that
>   represents a short-circuiting logical AND of this predicate and
>   another.

The resulting predicate is **returned** and not modified by reference, so you need to assign it, as stated by @Zircon in comment (`predicate = predicate.and(...)`).